# ImageResizer license monitoring

Tags: imageresizer

We are configuring IR license monitoring to be informed about expiration in advance.

Could you please suggest how can we can **get license information externally**, not from localhost?

We are interested in any kind of request that returns license expiration date.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That endpoint is /resizer.license

For example, ours can be seen here http://z.zr.io/resizer.license

There's not currently a JSON equivalent endpoint.

Comment: Thank you. It works for us. But yes, JSON would be easier to parse.